# Converting oracle to mysql to select listagg and left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please, I have the below oracle query to select post and list all share image attached to a post and at the same time join user table and post table. My problem now is to run this query in MySQL. I have tried so many modifications but it kept giving me errors can someone help out?

```
SELECT 
        post_image_id,
        LISTAGG(photo_url, ", ") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY photo_url) imgs
        FROM social_post_photos
        GROUP BY post_image_id;

        WITH i AS (
          SELECT post_image_id,
            LISTAGG(photo_url, ", ") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY photo_url) imgs
          FROM social_post_photos
          GROUP BY post_image_id
        )  

        SELECT sp.post_body_message, i.imgs AS images
        FROM social_posts sp
        LEFT JOIN vendor_account va
           ON sp.vendor_owner_id = va.eu_vendor_id
        LEFT JOIN i
           ON sp.social_page_id = i.post_image_id

           WHERE sp.social_page_id = 'page1'
           AND sp.vendor_owner_id = 'v100'
```

FULL DEMO WITH TABLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c39ef/2

Answer (score 0):

The mysql equivalent of listagg is group_concat -

```
SELECT 
        post_image_id,
        group_concat(photo_url ORDER BY photo_url) imgs
        FROM social_post_photos
        GROUP BY post_image_id;
```

There is no with(cte) in mysql until version 8 but i think you can replace this in your query with a sub query to create i.

Comment: Please help me, am getting error when i try to echo `post_body_message ` `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_body_message in` the meessage body is contained on `social_post` table